# Error in function and address pointer in string pointers

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program to find the length of string but the function name and char address seemed to always return an error

```
#ifndef LENGTH_STRING
#define LENGTH_STRING

#include<stdio.h>

int lengthString(char*){
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((*(char + i)) != '\0'){
        i += 1;
    }
} 

#endif
```

Error in function name: unnamed prototype parameters not allowed when body is present
error in + sign: expected a ")"
Error before ! sign: Expected an expression

Comment: Is this a .c or a .h? The #ifndef/#define/#endif make no sense if it's a .c, and the fact that the function is defined makes no sense if it's a .h.

Comment: `char + i` makes no sense. The error relates to that.

Comment: How do I access the next char in the string within a loop with the address though?

Comment: This looks like you tried to marry the function body to a prototype in the header directly. That your function takes an **unnamed** argument is a strong hint as to where the train left the tracks. But the deeper question is why are you coding a non-static, non-inline function *implementation* in a header file in the first place? What is the name of the C reference book you're using?

Answer (score 1):

`char + i` makes no sense. You meant to use the parameter, but you didn't give it a name!

You also forgot to return the size.

Fixed:

```c
int lengthString( char *str ) {
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ( (*(str + i) != '\0'){
        i += 1;
    }

    return i;
}
```

---

There are many improvements we can make.

- `size_t` is more appropriate for the size of memory blocks.
- Accepting constant strings is more flexible.
- `my_strlen` is more descriptive since you're recreating `strlen`.
- No reason to have the initialization of `i` on a different line.
- `x[y]` is so much clearer than 100% equivalent `*(x+y)`.
- `++i` is shorter than `i += 1`.

```c
size_t my_strlen( const char *str ) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( str[i] != '\0' ) {
        ++i;
    }

    return i;
}
```

---

We can keep going by removing some useless bits.

```c
size_t my_strlen( const char *str ) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( str[i] )
        ++i;

    return i;
}
```

`for` is just a fancy `while`.

```c
size_t my_strlen( const char *str ) {
    for ( size_t i=0; str[i]; ++i )
        /* nothing */;

    return i;
}
```

We could even use

```c
size_t my_strlen( const char *str ) {
    for ( size_t n=0; *(str++); ++n )
        /* nothing */;

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Or a loony `do`, e.g. `size_t len = 0; do {} while (str[len] && ++len); return len;`.